Configuring folder for path kafka-s3-connector from message
I have data of below mentioned format in AWS MSK. I want to push this data into AWS s3 bucket but I need to make the folder structure from the values of variables in the message. How do I do this using kafka-s3-connector?
I want this data to be stored with path

bucket-name/{schema-name}/{table-name}/{year}/{month}/{date}

{
    "data": {
        "id": 630
    },
    "beforeData": {
        "id": 630
    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2024-10-24T06:09:56.659338Z",
        "record-type": "data",
        "operation": "update",
        "partition-key-type": "schema-table",
        "schema-name": "customers_dev",
        "table-name": "customer_con",
        "transaction-id": 3823339587959
    }
}


You'll need to write your own Partitioner implementation in Connect.
It's not possible to extract/route records to storage based on both field and Date. See https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/pull/251

correction: they will need to write Partitioner implementation. Similar to DefaultPartitioner or FieldPartitioner (!!). Refer to this repo: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/tree/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner

Will this FieldPartitioner.class not work here? @EdbE
https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/configuration_options.html#partitioner

@ShashwatAwasthi That won't parse your timestamp into year, month, day. Also, Kafka records have a timestamp themselves, so are you duplicating information?

you will need to extend the implementation of FieldPartitioner to build the S3 full path the way you mentioned, that would include schema, table, etc...
